# Distance to roads (spatial lines) in R

Tags: r, raster, spatial

I have been struggling for days to produce a raster that represents distance to roads. I have a spatial lines shape file of roads in my study region, and I want to produce a distance to road feature at the same resolution as my other covariates, 30-m pixels. I have tried several things over the last few days, but most recently I have turned my template raster into spatial points and used `gDistance`, but this seems to spin on and on to no end.
My landscape is somewhat large, but not enormous (~25000 km2), other spatial analysis doesnt take so long, even with large stacks of 100+ rasters. I am somewhat lost at this point, having tried most suggestions I've found on the web.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the line data or something in a similar format? Is it ok to project to planar coordinates and then work with the spatstat package?

Comment: Sure, I can provide the line data. I have not use the spatstat package, but that seems like it should be ok. However, I am not sure what the best way to share the data is here on stack overflow.

Comment: In the answer below I just used example data from the `sf` package in R. Reading in line data and converting to spatstat format is sometimes painfully slow if you have many lines. Maybe going through `as.linnet.SpatialLines` in `maptools` can speed up things, and maybe you could simplify the road network if it is very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Reading in shapefile data with `sf` (note the custom coordinate reference
system, CRS, used to project to flat space was found using
https://projectionwizard.org):

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
dat_path <- system.file("shape/olinda1.shp", package="sf")
dat <- st_read(dat_path)
#> Reading layer `olinda1' from data source `/usr/lib/R/site-library/sf/shape/olinda1.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 470 features and 6 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -34.91692 ymin: -8.044467 xmax: -34.82779 ymax: -7.954672
#> Geodetic CRS:  GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)
poly <- st_geometry(dat)
new_crs <- st_crs("+proj=tcea +lon_0=-34.87 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
flat_poly <- st_transform(poly, new_crs)
flat_lines <- st_boundary(flat_poly)
plot(flat_lines)
```

[image]

Converting to spatatstat format (note that spatstat does not do any automatic
unit conversion or naming, so that part of the code is just for nice display
purposes. Also the coordinates are shiftet so the origin is in the bottomleft
for nicer printed output, but if you ever convert back to other formats this
should be omitted to avoid misplacing the area on a map.)

```r
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: spatstat.geom
#> spatstat.geom 2.2-2.002
#> Loading required package: spatstat.core
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> spatstat.core 2.3-0.003
#> Loading required package: spatstat.linnet
#> spatstat.linnet 2.3-0
#> 
#> spatstat 2.2-0       (nickname: 'That's not important right now') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
flat_lines_psp <- as.psp(flat_lines)
flat_lines_psp
#> planar line segment pattern: 12235 line segments
#> window: rectangle = [-5172.766, 4653.619] x [-895506, -885510.1] units
L <- shift(flat_lines_psp, origin = "bottomleft")
unitname(L) <- "m"
L
#> planar line segment pattern: 12235 line segments
#> window: rectangle = [0, 9826.385] x [0, 9995.897] m
```

Default distmap with 128x128 pixels:

```r
system.time(D128pix <- distmap(L))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.527   0.000   0.527
D128pix
#> real-valued pixel image
#> 128 x 128 pixel array (ny, nx)
#> enclosing rectangle: [0, 9826.4] x [0, 9995.9] m
plot(D128pix, log = TRUE)
```

[image]

You can control the resolution of the distance map with either `dimyx`
(number of resulting pixels) or `eps` (pixel resolution/size):

```r
system.time(D512pix <- distmap(L, dimyx = 512))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   8.083   0.020   8.104
plot(D512pix, log = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
system.time(D20m <- distmap(L, eps = 20))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   7.704   0.000   7.704
plot(D20m, log = TRUE)
```

[image]

I think the code grows more or less linearly in the number of pixels and
in the number of line segments, so if you have many small line segments this
may take a very long time. At least in this example reducing the number of
lines by approximately a factor 2 reduces the computation time by a factor 2:

```r
Lsmall <- L[owin(c(2500,7500),c(2500,7500))]
Lsmall
#> planar line segment pattern: 5988 line segments
#> window: rectangle = [2500, 7500] x [2500, 7500] m
system.time(Dsmall512pix <- distmap(Lsmall, dimyx = 512))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   4.179   0.004   4.184
plot(Dsmall512pix, log = TRUE)
```

[image]